# Cannot understand why this error occurs - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I'm reasonably new to swift, im making a simple class to read and write data from a .plist. I cannot understand why I am getting this compiler error when declaring these constants.

```
class Data {

let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
let documentDirectory = paths[0] as! String 
}
```

error:

```
'Data.type' does not have a member named 'paths'
```

Comment: You need to paste the error.

Comment: [ERROR: 'Data.type' does not have a member named 'paths'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the value of a property based on another property. There's no guarantee that they will be initialized in any order. The only guarantee is that class properties are initialized before instance properties, hence the `Data.type` in the error message. It refers to the collection of all class properties.

There are many ways to resolve this. Here's mine:

```
class Data {

var documentDirectory : String!

init () {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    documentDirectory = paths[0] as! String 
}

}
```

Comment: thats what i ended up doing! thank you